# Is there a black&white option for color printer when using air print?

Tags: airprint

airprint is pretty cool. On my Mac and PC I could setup a separate profile to use my color printer in black&white mode. Is it possible to do the same when using air print from iphone/ipad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built-in AirPrint doesn't allow this sort of functionality as of iOS 4, but if you get the [HP ePrint app](http://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/hp-eprint-home-biz/id299531647?mt=8), you should be able to do B&W printing and manage other settings. This of course only works if you have an AirPrint/ePrint HP printer, it won't work with any other printer that you've hacked to set up with AirPrint.

Comment: I don't know how it worked in 2011. Today however, if the AirPrint device supports color, the iOS client will see an additional option to ask for Black+White printing (default is color). Once selected, the client will preview and send black+white PDF data to the AirPrinter.

Answer (score 1):

[Printopia for Mac](http://ecamm.com/mac/printopia) will let you configure what settings the printer will use when you AirPrint. For example, you can select to use B&W only.